# Why Visual Studio Code showing module as reserved keyword in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, visual-studio-code

I was testing angularjs in visual studio code. Two things to ask

Why `var module` is showing as reserved keyword?

I have attached 2 screen shots. 
Why `var module` showing different behavior if wrapped in an anonymous function than one outside of a function?

module inside of a function with . display proper intelli.

[image]
[image]

**More Screen Shots**

[image]
[image]
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a jsconfig.json?

Comment: @kevin-b, no jsconfig.json

Comment: `module` when using commonjs as your module system (which is configured using jsconfig.json, so you're using the default) is used for exporting something out of a module. It appears as though you're not writing commonjs modules, so you'll want to add a jsconfig.json and set the module property to a value that makes sense for your setup. It would need to be one of these values: `"commonjs", "amd", "umd", "system"`

Comment: looking more into jsconfig.json. thanks

Comment: Update your VSCode, and the syntax highlighting will be fixed. Previously keywords always got recognized as normal keyword even if the place it was used is not possible for a keyword to be in. Like this: `{enum: 5}` or `promise.catch(...)`.

Comment: @Zenorbi, Again downloaded and installed 0.9.1 version. But problem still there. Got to live with that?

Comment: @Pirzada, sorry I didn't notice the `.js` extensions. I was annoyed by this bug in TypeScript and got fixed today, so I thought this is just before the update. I guess you should report the bug at https://code.visualstudio.com/Issues/List